# Hadoop Configuration Object ClassPath

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to get a `FileSystem` instance for my hadoop HDFS inside a spark driver program which would run on `YARN`; for that I first need to get a configuration object which initially reads core-default.xml  which I have seen is already provided inside the library jar( that contains Configuration object) and then it reads core-site.xml and as per [this offical page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html), it reads them from the `classpath`. Because when I intialise a filesystem using this conf it points to the local filesyem. So I think I am missing something and that is probably incorrect `classpath`. I am not sure about what it means by `classpath`. Since it's a spark program I would have spark-driver classpath and  the executor classpath. I don't think its referring to them.
Also, I know I can simply add the core-site.xml file to the configuration object as a resource but I need to do it without that because I have to make use of some code which simply creates a configuration object that somehow already has the key-value pairs from the core-site.xml file present in the hadoop conf directory.(ofcourse it's reading the `core-site.xml` file from the "classpath").
 Any idea on this?
Even some online resource explaining the in-depth working of spark or hadoop would be good.

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/85757/how-to-add-the-hadoop-and-yarn-configuration-file.html

Comment: Classpath is a Java term, not Spark or Hadoop. But if you want YARN integrations you need to setup your HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable, as the documentation says

Comment: I am running the code in intellij in which the run configuration has the HADOOP_CONF_DIR set as a parent environemnt variable. But it's still not picking up the core-site.xml file.

Comment: I have never had much luck with the intellij environment variables. Have you tried setting it as the OS level? Alternatively, can't you just specify `hdfs://NAMENODE:8020/file` for your tasks?